# Jquery Fancy Box with thumbnails housing separate galleries

Tags: jquery, fancybox, gallery

I'm trying to alter my fancybox so that each thumbnail when clicked opens into a  different gallery. Right now fancy box just scrolls through all the thumbnails shown.

I've looked up multiple ways to do this, many including a rel, and hiddden tags but nothing overall seems to be working.

Thoughts?
Basically right now I have a page set up on column system. 3x3 grid of thumbs and want each one to open up a gallery of their own images.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Just make only first thumbnail visible for each gallery.

Check first example from documentation - http://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/jyEGGG/?editors=1000

```
<h3>Gallery with one preview image</h3>
<p>
    <a href="https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/357/31876784275_12286240d4_h.jpg" data-fancybox="images-single">
      <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/357/31876784275_fbc9696913_m.jpg" />
    </a>
</p>

<div style="display: none;">

  <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2947/33594572585_b48eba935b_k_d.jpg" data-fancybox="images-single"
     data-thumb="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2947/33594572585_46ca00f3a5_m_d.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2859/33395734202_522f9d8efd_k_d.jpg" data-fancybox="images-single"
     data-thumb="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2859/33395734202_15a81c4ef3_m_d.jpg"></a>

</div>
```